# Get Context Data on Attribute within Model in Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to filter all reviews that correspond to listings created by a certain viewer. The purpose is to put all the reviews someone has received on their listings on a profile page. I am able to use get_context_data to pull in the listing reviews, but I want to filter on a relationship within the listing itself.

***Views.py:***

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Profile
    template_name = 'account/profile_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'profile_detail'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reviews'] = RentalListingReviews.objects.filter(RentalListing.lender = self.request.user)
        return context
```

***Models.py:***

```
class RentalListing(models.Model):

    item_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    lender = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rental_listing_detail', args=[str(self.item_id)])

class RentalListingReviews(models.Model):

    listing = models.ForeignKey(
        RentalListing,
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
        related_name = 'listing_reviews',
    )
    review = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rental_listing_detail', args=[str(self.listing.item_id)])
```

Comment: Here is the error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'RentalListing' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, id, listing, listing_id, review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```py
RentalListingReviews.objects.filter(listing__lender = self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a RentalListing field in a function call.

```
context['reviews'] = RentalListingReviews.objects.filter(RentalListing.lender = self.request.user)
```

Should be ->

```
context['reviews'] = RentalListingReviews.objects.filter(lender = self.request.user)
```